# Match names with R for each element of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames:

```
data1 <- data.frame(names = c("ALBERT | ALBERTIS 2", 
                              "PIERRE | JEAN | ALBERT", 
                              "ALBERTOS"))
data2 <- data.frame(names_search = c("ALBERT", "PIERRE"))
```

I want to know that each whole WORD of `data2` is present in `data1`. A new column in `data1` will contain those elements matched.
So I want a result like:

```
data3 <- data.frame(names = c("ALBERT | ALBERTOS | ALBERT 2", 
                              "ALBERT | ALBERTOS | ALBE 2",
                              "PIERRE | PIERRE 2 | PIERRE_SECOND | PIERRE_SECOND 2"), 
                    names_search = c("ALBERT", "ALBERT | PIERRE", ""))
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?

I tried this in double loop (hope you can give a better way) but it failed.

```
for( i in 1:nrow(data1)){
  result <- ""
  for(j in 1: nrow(data2)){
     present <- grepl(eval(parse(text = paste0('\\<',data2$names_search[j],'\\>'))), data1$names[i], fixed = T)
     # I check if the whole word data[j] is present in data1[i]

     if(present ==T){
       result <- paste(result, data2$names_search[j], sep= "|")

     }


  }
  data1$names_search[i] <- result

}
```

Comment: Thank you for refomating my questions. It seems an issue in grepl I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the strings (i.e. each line) at `" | "` using `strsplit`; thereafter we just subset each iteration with the match vector of `data2` if it's `%in%`side. At the end, the `if` handles the case when there is no match, the `else` `paste`s the result into the desired form.

```
data1 <- transform(
  data1, 
  names_search=sapply(strsplit(as.character(data1$names), " | ", fixed=TRUE), function(x) {
    out <- x[x %in% data2$names_search]
    if (length(out) == 0) NA_character_
    else paste(out, collapse=" | ")
  }))
```

### Result

```
data1
#                    names names_search
# 1    ALBERT | ALBERTIS 2   ALBERTIS 2
# 2 PIERRE | JEAN | ALBERT       PIERRE
# 3               ALBERTOS         <NA>
```

---

*Data*

```
data1 <- structure(list(names = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("ALBERT | ALBERTIS 2", 
"ALBERTOS", "PIERRE | JEAN | ALBERT"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

data2 <- structure(list(names_search = structure(1:2, .Label = c("ALBERTIS 2", 
"PIERRE"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Wahoo, That works perfectly, I will apply that on my whole database. as a beginner in R, could I have few words explaning your function?

Comment: @DDchen Done, added some explanations!

Comment: if I have "ALBERTIS 2" in my data2 , this doesn't work well. Do you have an idea if I have this data2 to be mached? : ```data2 <- structure(list(names_search = structure(1:2, .Label = c("ALBERT 2", 
                                                                 "PIERRE"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                    -2L))```

Comment: I'm afraid that you already answer my question in your explanations.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want `ALBERT 2` to be matched with `ALBERT` or whether this is no match?

Comment: You are right , I re-edit my comment,  I want to match "ALBERTIS 2" which is present in data1 (first row)

Comment: because I consider the whole string in each row of data2 as a WORD, and match it in data1, that's why T started by using grepl with backslash. thank you very much!!!

Comment: @DDchen I see, there was a misunderstanding. Try edited answer, should work fine now.